# Background Image not Displaying Correctly in Div Using CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, background-image

I have a site in which the header image is not displaying correctly in mobile. I'm using bootstrap 4, so the site should be responsive. But when I load my site in mobile browser the header image repeats. I remove the no-repeate in css, but then the image covers half of the div, the other half is blank. The header works just fine in laptop, and desktop. is just mobile I'm having problem displaying.
here's the site [JV Computers](http://jvpcs.org)

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- PAGE settings -->
  <link rel="icon" href="https://templates.pingendo.com/assets/Pingendo_favicon.ico">
  <title>JV Computer Service</title>
  <meta name="description" content="JV Computer Service main page">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Desktop Support, Computer Repair, Virus Removal, Data Recovery, Server Administration, Printer Repair, Network Installation, Wireless, Website Development">
  <meta name="author" content="JV Computer Servic"e>
  <!-- CSS dependencies -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="wireframe.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container"> <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right border-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar13">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar13"> <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-block" href="#">
          <img class="head-logo" src="../../work/graphics/logo.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="" >
          <b><span class="title"> JV Computer Service</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; (305) 680 4659</b>
        </a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="services.html">Services</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="index.html#about">About</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="support.html">Support</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="index.html#contact">Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="https://twitter.com/geoVT25" target="_blank">
              <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i>
            </a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/pctechtips25" target="_blank">
              <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i>
            </a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOH7oeWBE2pgcFPFmj7lCqw" target="_blank">
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-youtube"></i>
            </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="text-center py-5 head-section" >
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row my-5 justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <h1><strong>Simplified IT Solutions</strong></h1>
          <h2 class="bg-warning">Technology solutions for small business and homes</h2>
          <a href="#services" class="btn m-2 btn-success">learn more</a>
          <a href="#contact" class="btn m-2 btn-success">get support</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="py-4 bg-light" id="services">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1 class="text-center">Services</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="lead text-center">Bellow you can see a brief description of our services and price. These fall into three main category: Desktop Support, System Maintanance, and Network Installation. If you would like to know more details, go to the Service page.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 p-3">
          <div class="card box-shadow rounded border border-secondary" >
            <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/styleguide/thinkstockphotos-479282847.jpg">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="text-center">Desktop Support</h3>
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">learn more</a>
                <h5 contenteditable="true">60 $ 1hr</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 p-3">
          <div class="card box-shadow border border-secondary rounded">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/styleguide/photo-1506399309177-3b43e99fead2.jpg">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="text-center">System Administration</h3>
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">learn more</a>
                <h5 style="">100 $ 1hr</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 p-3">
          <div class="card box-shadow border border-secondary rounded">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/styleguide/photo-1544197150-b99a580bb7a8.jpg">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="text-center">Network Installation</h3>
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">learn more</a>
                <h5>150 $ 1hr</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="py-5 text-center bg-primary" id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1 class="mb-3">About Us</h1>
          <p>JV Computer Service is a small Computer Repair and IT Solution company. It's own and operated by its owner who has over 20 years experience in the computer and IT field. He acquired most of his experience working for the school district and managing and supporting multiple schools with over 500 computers.&nbsp;During that time he was responsible for providing user support, and system administration​.<br>He was responsible for the management and completion of several projects.&nbsp;One project, involved the installation of more than 100 computers in a new student building. This project included physical installation of PC's, cabling,&nbsp;and rolling out the operating system and different application.&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="py-5 bg-dark" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="mx-auto text-center col-lg-8">
          <h1 class="mb-3">Contact Us</h1>
          <p class="lead mb-4">If you experiencing any computer issues, lets us assist you. Fill the form bellow with a description and phone</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="p-0 order-2 order-md-1 col-lg-6"> <iframe width="100%" height="350" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;q=New%20York&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe> </div>
        <div class="px-4 order-1 order-md-2 col-lg-6">
          <h2 class="mb-4">Create a ticket</h2>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form44" placeholder="Name"> </div>
            <div class="form-group"> <input type="email" class="form-control" id="form45" placeholder="Email"> </div>
            <div class="form-group"> <textarea class="form-control" id="form46" rows="3" placeholder="Your message"></textarea> </div> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="py-5 bg-secondary text-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="float-right text-dark">
        <a href="#">Back to top</a>
      </p>
      <p>JV Computer Service website was designed with Pingendo and Bootstrap<br>All rights reserved JV Computer Service LLT</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS code

```
.head-logo {
    background-image: url(assets/styleguide/logo.png);
    background-position: top left;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat;"
}

.title {
    color:#f9b751;
}

.head-section {
    background-image: url(assets/styleguide/jonathan-SwVkmowt7qA-unsplash.jpg); 
    background-position: left top;  
    background-size: 100%;  
    background-repeat: repeat;
}   

.card {
    border-style: solid;
}

.card-img-top {
    background-position: top left;  
    background-size: 100%;  
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to happen in mobile?  If you don't want it to repeat, and you don't want the other half of the header to be blank, describe exactly what should happen. Do you want the image to be scaled so it's as tall as the header, and then only the leftmost part of the image will show?

Comment: remove " from your css code 
    background-repeat: repeat;

Comment: css for .head-logo is not valid, and that's why styles not applied

Comment: please try to reduce the font size of banner content in mobile view using media query for better background image visibility.

Answer (score 2):

this should do it: `background-size: cover;`

Comment: I thought background-size: 100% was pretty much the same as cover. but apparently not..